# How to vectorize matlab function input when NaN could be the input?

Tags: arrays, matlab, performance, if-statement, vectorization

I wrote a function which I hope to have vectorized input and output:

```
function output = myfunction(input1,input2)
if input1 == 0
    output = equation1 ;
else
    output = equation2 ;
end
```

I tested it with `input1 = 0` and `input1 = 0.5` and `myfunction` works right.  `input1` and `input2` are actually 3D matrices. I am trying to have more efficient computation instead of running a loop for an element by element calculation.

If `input1` are all nonzero elements, `myfunction` works correctly. It seems like once I input a matrix with zero and nonzero elements, it cannot go through the `if-statement` correctly. My function will give me NaN for the element that has `input1==0`.

How can I change it so that `myfunction` can take either a number or a matrix in an `if-statement`?

Thank you!

[EDIT:]

The actual function looks like this:

```
function output = myfunction( input1 , frequency , input2 , input3 )

zero_ind = input1 == 0 ;
output = zeros(size(input1)) ;
output(zero_ind) = input3(zero_ind) / frequency ./ input2(zero_ind) ; ;
temp1(~zero_ind) = input1(~zero_ind) / frequency ;
temp2(~zero_ind) = input2(~zero_ind) * frequency ;
output(~zero_ind) = input3(~zero_ind) .*  ( 1 + temp1(~zero_ind)).^temp2(~zero_ind) .* temp1(~zero_ind) ./ ( ( 1 + temp1(~zero_ind) ).^temp2(~zero_ind) - 1 ) ;
```

Comment: Do both equations use `input1` and `input2`?

Comment: `equation1` use input2 and `equation2` use input1 and input2. Will that make anything difference?

Comment: Its not exactly clear to me what you want to do. Is `all(input1(:))` what you're looking for?

Comment: I am trying to explain it clearly. Could you please tell me where you don't get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a general suggestion for vectorizing. This should be changed properly to your kind of calculations:

```
function output = myfunction(input1,input2)
zero_ind = input1==0; % this replaces the if statement
output = zeros(size(input1)); % initialize output to wanted size and shape
output(zero_ind) = input2(zero_ind).^2; % equation1
output(~zero_ind) = input1(~zero_ind).*input2(~zero_ind); % equation2
end
```

The main idea is to use [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1) instead of the `if` statement. I assume here (among other things, I guess) that all your inputs and output are the same sizes. This could be relaxed, but it depends on the specific calculation you do.

EDIT:

In response to your edit with the real function, here is my suggestion (I changed the input names just to make it a little more compact):

```
function output = myfunction(in1,frequency,in2,in3)
temp1 = in1/frequency ;
temp2 = in2*frequency ;
output = in3.*(1+temp1).^temp2.*temp1./((1+temp1).^temp2-1);
zero_ind = in1 == 0;
output(zero_ind) = in3(zero_ind)./frequency./in2(zero_ind); 
end
```

What I did is calculating all `output` like there are no zeros in `in1`, and then replace only the places in `output` that corresponds to a zero in `in1` to another value. This way you use `zero_ind` only when necessary, and minimize the indexing operation.

Comment: Yes, I adjust the input variable to the same size to avoid using bsxfun which I am not really familiar. I guess it might be a workable solution, but my `equation2` has to use `(~zero_ind)` maybe 8 times. And it seems like it is taking too much memory and have the following message. 

    `Requested 249901x249901 (465.3GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference. Creation of arrays greater than this limit may take a long time and cause MATLAB to become unresponsive. See array size limit or preference panel for more information.`

Comment: @Ying First, vectorization is not a magic, it takes a lot of memory to make things faster. This is a basic trade-off between memory and speed. Second, I think you may approach this problem in a wrong way, it could be that you should get familiar with `bsxfun` (which is implicitly implemented since 2016b). Either way, I can't help you more than this without seeing your real calculation. Your question is simply too vague.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning logical indexing. Is it a method that will take lots of memory during computation?

Comment: It takes as much memory as your input size, not more than that, even if you use it several times.

Comment: I am editing my questions to reflect the original code. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the trick and explanation! That's clever! It saved lots of memories.